# In ASP.net, Without using browser Cookies can we track user system?

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.net,

Without using browser Cookies  can we track user system? actually we have requirement where we generate URL and send email to user with URL and when user clicks on the URL I need to know whether user is authorized to view WebPage or not.

Please help me, how to track user.

Thanks,

Sukesh.

Answer (score 0):

You could restrict access by IP address.

There are also ways other than cookies to store auth info, i.e. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2796/Cookieless-ASP-NET-forms-authentication

Comment: Thanks for reply, Here once user clicks on the URL from his email,we need to allow user to main screen by skipping login page. Generally at this time we don't have credentials.

Comment: then just put a unguessable token (like a password) in the link in the email - on the asp.net page, look for that token, and log them in if you find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have cookieless sessions via the `sessionState` element's `cookieless` attribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply, Here once user clicks on the URL from his email, we need to allow user to main screen by skipping login page. Generally at this time we don't have credentials